# How to ignore case for POJO if it extends an abstract class in Spring Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I know we can ignore case for input JSON by adding property in application.yml as:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      accept_case_insensitive_properties: true
```

But if my POJO extends an abstract class, it is not working and my JSON is not being parsed.

My abstract class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "event")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Orders.class, name = "orders"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WorkOrders.class, name = "workOrders")
})
public abstract class ElasticDocument {
// Fields and getter/setter
}
```

My Pojo:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class Orders extends ElasticDocument {
//other fields

private List<OrderLine> orderLines;

}
```

Input JSON which I am getting from input has different case e.g.

```
{
  "event": "orders", 
  "OrderNo": 12345,
  "Status": "Created",
  "CustomerZipCode": "23456",
  "CustomerFirstName": "firstname1",
  "orderType": "PHONEORDER",
  "customerLastName": "lastname1",
  "OrderLines": [
    {
      "LineName": "sample"
    }
  ]
}
```

My contoller method where I am using this `ElasticDocument` object:

```
@PostMapping("save")
public Orders save(@RequestBody ElasticDocument elasticDocument) {
    return elasticsearchRepository.save((Orders) elasticDocument);
}
```

I am using `Spring-boot version 2.2.4`

Comment: **accept_case_insensitive_properties**  is used to desearialize incoming json (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES). Is this your case? Or Do you need to create a json with  **myProperty** from **MyProperty** ?

Comment: Yeah this is my case. I explained the same in my question that I need to deserialize the input json to one of my abstract class implementation.

Comment: desearialize word does not exist in your question :s. #1 try to improve your question comparing the incoming json, the pojo and null values after deserealization process. #2 use **accept_case_insensitive_properties** is mandatory for you? There are a couple of ways to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `@type` to your request JSON.`@type` is to identify the type of `ElasticDocument` being serialized.

Here is a example that i tried in my local system with minimum fields in class:

**ElasticDocument.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Orders.class, name = "Orders"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WorkOrders.class, name = "workOrders")
})
public abstract class ElasticDocument {
    private Integer docId;
    private String docName;
   // getters and setters
}
```

**Orders.java**

```
public class Orders extends ElasticDocument{
    private Integer orderId;
    private String orderName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**WorkOrders.java**

```
public class WorkOrders extends ElasticDocument{
    private Integer workOrderId;
    private String workOrderName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**StackOverflowController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class StackOverflowController {

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    ElasticDocument createOrder(@RequestBody ElasticDocument order){
        return order;
    }
}
```

When i send data like this to my endpoint (Please note the attributes name in json are lowercase)

```
{
    "@type":"workOrders",
    "docId":123,
    "docName":"XXXX",
    "orderid":45,
    "ordername":"shoe",
    "workorderid":324,
    "workordername":"dsf"
}
```

It is converted to workOrders response:

```
{
    "@type": "workOrders",
    "docId": 123,
    "docName": "XXXX",
    "workOrderId": 324,
    "workOrderName": "dsf"
}
```

And when i changed the `@type` to `Orders` in request then i will get Order response:

```
{
    "@type": "Orders",
    "docId": 123,
    "docName": "XXXX",
    "orderId": 45,
    "orderName": "shoe"
}
```

Comment: To get the type information I have added property named `event` in the json as I mentioned above ElasticDocument class in `@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "event")`. I have updated my input json in question also. I will also try  your solution and will update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES` instead of `accept_case_insensitive_properties`
Also in case you use enum-type property then use `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS`